# How to see area and boundary measurement with Folium Draw plugin

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, leaflet, gis, folium

[image]

I'm working with Jupyter and Folium , and using the Draw plugin. In my code I have:

```
from folium.plugins import Draw
m = Map(location=CENTER, zoom_start=15)
# Add GeoJSON data layer to the map
GeoJson(geojson_data).add_to(m)

# Draw(export=True).add_to(m)
Draw(
export=True,
filename="my_data.geojson",
position="topleft",
draw_options={"polyline": {"allowIntersection": False,"showLength":True},"polygon": {"showArea": True,"showLength":True}},
# edit_options={"poly": {"allowIntersection": False}}
).add_to(m)
```

After completing a polygon, I don't see the area or length of the boundary, even though the option says true. Why not?

Comment: Maybe related : [GH/467](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/467) and [Q/74982953](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74982953/leaflet-draw-does-not-show-the-area-of-the-polygon). Using [`MeasureControl`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/latest/user_guide/plugins/measure_control.html) could be a *workaround*.